# Dependencies between Android native modules (prefab) fail to build

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-native-library, prefab

Our Android application consists of 40-some Android Library Modules (ALMs), each of which also builds a C++ shared library with `externalNativeBuild` and CMake. So far we had the dependencies between these libs set up like this:

- The dependent ALM references the dependency ALM with `api project(':lib')`
- The dependent CMake script references the dependency .so with `add_library(SHARED IMPORTED lib)` and `set_target_properties(lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ...)` and a relative path.

Recently we had to upgrade to the latest Android API version. This started off a cascade because now we were getting deprecated warnings in code generated by the navigation-ktx library, but upgrading that requires upgrading Gradle and the Android Gradle plugin. After that I started getting errors like `liblib.so, needed by 'project', missing and no known rule to make it`.

It looks like the latest Gradle parallelizes build tasks more heavily, and this means the dependent CMake/Ninja builds are being started concurrently with their dependencies, resulting in this error because the dependency is not yet built. I figured out that what we were doing was not entirely supported, but there is a "supported" way to do that now, so I refactored our entire build to use [Prefab](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#native-dependencies-aars).

Now I started getting other errors, alternating between:

1.

```
C++ build system [prefab] failed while executing ...
Usage: prefab [OPTIONS] PACKAGE_PATH...
Error: Invalid value for "PACKAGE_PATH": Directory ... is not readable.
```

2. `ld: error: undefined symbol ...`

I looked into `build/intermediates` and found that in the 2nd case, the cmake config script was generated incorrectly: instead of `add_library(lib::lib SHARED IMPORTED )` it had `add_library(lib::lib INTERFACE IMPORTED)` like it it was a header only library, and there was no `IMPORTED_LOCATION` set in the file.

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to unbreak our build?

Comment: Have you figured out a workaround for this?

Comment: @MEE I'm in the middle of refactoring our entire build into just one ALM

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the toolchain support for prefab interdependencies within a project is not quite finished. Others are reporting the same kind of errors at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265544858:

> This appears to be a race condition with generating prefab cmake files.

It says in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221231432 that the header-only cmake config is generated to satisfy Android Studio's IDE features (completion, etc.) before the library is actually built.

> Treat as-yet-unconfigured modules as if they are Header-only libraries for Android Studio purposes. This works because Android Studio doesn't care about linker flags for the purposes of providing language services.